# Re-normalize feature vectors after feature selection

Tags: svm, scikit-learn, document-classification

I've performed χ² feature selection on my training documents already transformed to TF*IDF feature vectors using [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer), which produces normalized vectors by default. However, after selecting the top-K most informative features, the vectors are no longer normalized due to the removing of dimensions (all vectors are now with length < 1).

Is it advisable to re-normalize the feature vectors after feature selection? I'm also not very clear of the main difference B/T normalization and scaling. Do they server similar purposes for learners such as SVC?

Thank you in advance for your kind answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a lot of questions in one. The main reason for doing normalization on tf-idf vectors is so that their dot products (used by SVMs in their decision function) are readily interpretable as [cosine similarities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), the mainstay of document vector comparisons in information retrieval. Normalization makes sure that

```
"hello world"             -> [1 2]
"hello hello world world" -> [2 4]
```

become the same vector, so concatenating a document onto itself doesn't change the decision boundary and the similarity between these two documents is exactly one (although with sublinear scaling, `sublinear_tf` in the vectorizer constructor, this is no longer true).

The main reasons for doing scaling is to [avoid numerical instability issues](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf). Normalization takes care of most of those because features will already be in the range [0, 1]. (I think it also relates to regularization, but I don't use SVMs that often.)

As you've noticed, chi² "denormalizes" feature vectors, so to answer the original question: you can try renormalizing them. I did that when adding chi² feature selection to the scikit-learn document classification example, and it helped with some estimators and hurt with others. You can also try doing the chi² on unnormalized tf-idf vectors (in which case I recommend you try setting `sublinear_tf`) and do either scaling or normalization afterwards.

Comment: thank you @larsmans for your great answer. I will experiment with your suggestions.